# Tables - One row at top and the other at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have an table like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is at the top of the page</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>This is at the bottom of the page</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I make for the first row be at the top of the page, and the second at the bottom of it?

I tried with `position:absolute` and `top:0px`, but it makes me unable to put colored backgrounds and borders in the table...

Comment: Seems like a terrible idea to use a table for this.  Tables are for grid layouts, not for this kind of thing.

Comment: ok, thank you... i'll try to use divs instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use div for this issue :

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#top {
  position:absolute 
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
}
#bottom {
  position:absolute 
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `TABLE` element is not a good idea. Using of `DIV` elements is much better because you
can adjust `DIV` elements as you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table height="100%"> 
  <tr> 
    <td>This is at the top of the page</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td height="100%"></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>This is at the bottom of the page</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: I agree DIVs and CSS are better approaches, but the OP said he had a table, so I presented a solution for his table.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead with Sirwan's answer, as it is the **correct** way to do it! Moreover, now that HTML5 has made its foray into the picture you could use the ***< header >*** and ***< footer >*** tags for what you are trying to achieve.

*HEADER* : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp
*FOOTER* : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp